# handsontable removes and adds cells to the table, how to prevent this?

Tags: handsontable

Handsontable will all an remove off screen cells form the table while scrolling left and right.

How can I stop this. I want all cells to be there, on or off-screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use **renderAllRows: true** in your handsontable definition